# How can I change required fields based on button pressed?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm not sure if this is possible or not. Basically, here is what I have. My form has 3 buttons at the end of it, Cancel, Save and Submit.  All the fields are required to be able to submit the form. I got around the validations for the cancel button by using the `cancel` class and also using `ModelState.Clear()` (since I am using both client side and server side validation).

How can I make only one field be required if the user presses the save button?

My code is too big to actually show examples of, but here is the basics:

In my model, all the fields have the property `[Required]`

In my view, the validation is shown with `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Level)`

My controller has cases for each button pressed:

```
if(button == "cancel")
{
    ModelState.Clear();  <- This turns off server-side validation
    //returns to other page
}

if(button == "save")
{
    //save things?  <-- Not sure what to do here?
}

if(button == "submit")
{
    //submit everything
}
```

Basically I want to turn off client-side and server-side validation for everything except the one necessary field.

Comment: How will you validate the data on server-side in case of save.

Comment: If the user is saving something, the only field I need to be required is the Title.  I'm using DataAnnotations for my validations.

Comment: add the code examples to your question

Comment: for the client-side make sure that Title is not null and check the contents of other fields.then you can save.. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered this myself using javascript:

First I switched the validation message to one that I could control (since I couldn't figure out how to control the Html.ValidationMessageFor() myself).

`<div class="validate-event-name hidden">Event Name Required</div>`

Then I added this javascript function

```
    $('#newForm').submit(function checkEventName(event) {
        if ($('#EventName').val() == "") {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.validate-event-name.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
        }
    });
```

This shows the validation message without submitting the form. Then I used `ModelState.Clear()` for my save button in the controller and voila!

I hope this helps someone since it took me a while to figure out.

(P.S. Downvoting my question without explaining why really isn't helpful to me. It was a legitimate question!)

Comment: That's great.Keep going.